# How can i solve this error, i don't understand what is happening?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, redux, mobile-application

[image]

how can i correct this code?
tell me please,
it is working perfectly before changing the simulator after that it is happening

Comment: What script/command are you trying to run? 

from the error log I see, that there is an unknown service: package

Comment: Can you share your input and output as text not as image? It is much better to read :-)